# How I make celery worker to listen to a queue which is on another server

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

Suppose one celery worker is running on server say x.y.a.b and let's say the rabbitmq server is running on server x.y.a.c and it has two queues P and Q. Now, I want this celery worker to listen to P queue which is another server. How to do this?

Comment: this is basically how everyone setup their rabbitmq server. just config worker connect server via hostname or ip address of server node, ref http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html